# A challenge to put your head against

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Put on the sheet, I look like myself,
> Sheet put on me, from off of the shelf.
> From wood, water, grain, bird or bear,
> Upon me, your body oft shall bare.
>
> Above are the first hints given for test,
> Afterwards, I will help give you the rest.

Who am I?

> Not a hint: Deep apologies for the bare bear rhyme, I couldn't bear passing the opportunity for lazy wordplay replacing a rhyme. Truth be told I oft think my poetry a crime.

Comment: I've considered copier and silouette, but what it is I probably won't get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's:

> A bed

Put on the sheet, I look like myself

> When photographed and printed on a **sheet** of paper

Sheet put on me, from off of the shelf

> A bed **sheet** (a.k.a bed linen) is typically stored on a **shelf** in a linen closet

From wood, water, grain, bird or bear

> Beds can be made from **wood**, there are **water** beds, some futons are filled with **grain**, bird feathers can be used fill mattresses, bear skin rugs can both adorn beds and bear skin were traditionally used as the bed itself in Scandinavia (and probably other cold climate locations)

Upon me, your body oft shall bare

> When I lie on a bed, it **bares** my weight

Author's Notes:

> Title: A challenge to put your head against, you sort of put your head on the bed to sleep (depending on your thoughts as a bed entailing the pillow)
>  Put on the sheet I look like myself the word -- bed -- looks like a bed. It has the head and tail boards and a flat middle. kinda like how the word shark looks vaguely like a shark.
>  Upon me your body oft shall bare, bare means to be naked against not carry. And bare skin often touches a bed.
>  Afterwards I will help give you the rest -> bed helps you rest.

Comment: You are correct, it is bed, there are 3 other hints, if you got 2 more of them I would be quite happy giving the correct answer check. (might give it anyways in a few hours, but I wouldn't mind seeing it fully explained out.

Comment: @Going I had added what I think are the missing explanations

Comment: Edited to include intended details.

Answer (score 1):

> PILLOW

Put on the sheet, I look like myself,

> We usually put our pillow *on* the bed i.e. on the bed's sheet

Sheet put on me, from off of the shelf.

> Same with other parts of the bed we cover our pillows with some piece of cloth

From wood, water, grain, bird or bear,

> Material used to make pillows. Cloth, feathers or grain inside, maybe furr on the outside?

Upon me, your body oft shall bare.

> We rest/sleep on it. Maybe from a fight with wood, water, grain, bird or a bear ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it

> Is a pillow.  It keeps its shape when it is covered by a pillow case, which should be often washed and put back on the pillow.  Also under the assumption of it being pillow, look at the title.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Our DNA/DNA test

Who are you?

> Everyone

Put on the sheet, I look like myself,

> DNA is a representation of one's self. Although you wouldn't recognize it, on a sheet of paper it would be you.

Sheet put on me, from off of the shelf.

> DNA is conveyed finally on paper. The paper used for a DNA sequencer comes, presumably, from off a shelf.

From wood, water, grain, bird or bear,

> All have a DNA signature

Interesting read on less organic water.

> http://www.i-sis.org.uk/DNA_sequence_reconstituted_from_Water_Memory.php

Upon me, your body oft shall bare.

> We can know much about our bodies from our DNA. In essence, our true selves are laid bare by our indisputable DNA.

Above are the first hints given for test,

> DNA test

Afterwards, I will help give you the rest.

> Afterwards we'll have more intrinsic knowledge about who the person is and from where they come.

Bonus on the no hint: Truth be told I oft think my poetry a crime.

> Can we use DNA to identify the person or persons who write bad poetry?

Comment: That link is pseudoscience, unfortunately.

Comment: @Deusovi, what makes you say that? :) Water, almost always has organic matter, this article only explores a far more interesting idea. Water on Mars perhaps? There is, for example, no reason to think that DNA doesn't leave an imprint much like fossils too. It is tangible if only by very very small hands.

Comment: I-SIS is [not a reliable source](http://www.dcscience.net/2006/07/19/institute-of-science-in-society/). They have several articles on homeopathy, which is complete bunk.

Comment: In general, anything referring to the "memory of water" is not to be trusted.

Comment: Thank you! c: "Exploring interesting ideas" is always a good thing, and I wholly encourage it, but "water memory" has no plausible mechanism and mountains of evidence against it.

Comment: @Deusovi Well, I've never seen a glass of water that remembered me, so I believe you. Maybe that's just one of water's many evasive qualities.

Comment: @Deusovi, I expect that you being the new moderator, that my answer is free from defect, therefore correct. :)

Comment: Hey, I never made *any* remarks about the correctness of the answer. :P I'm not the riddle-setter here. (That being said, apart from the "water" thing it seems at least plausible.)